# git submodule status vs git status submodule

Tags: git

What is the difference between `git submodule status` and `git status submodule`?

`git submodule status` is often seen in several answers. Currently, it doesn't give me any output.
`git status submodule` tells me:

```
On branch main
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 8 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

The latter command was more a typo. Now I'm suprised that it gives an output at all.
I have submodules but no folder named `submodule`.

Comment: I suppose git just queries internal registry if anything related with `./submodule` path is changed. And since nothing containing `./submodule` path is found, the output is as such. It doesn't even check if the path exists, it checks if anything related is recorded

Answer (score 1):

- `git submodule status` runs the `git submodule` command and asks it to check on submodule status.  This will look at each submodule, and for each one that you have or don't have, report its status.  For instance, run in a clone of the Git repository for Git, I get:

  ```
  $ git submodule status
  -855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2 sha1collisiondetection
  ```

  because I never told Git to clone or check out the `sha1collisiondetection` submodule.
- `git status submodule` runs the`git status` command, asking it to report the status of any file named `submodule`.  It will first produce the overall status that it normally produces.  After that, if you *do* have a file named `submodule`, it will say what it would have said about that file had you run `git status` without limiting its output.  If you *don't* have a file named `submodule`, it would not have said anything in the first place, and it continues to say nothing.

In other words, one of these actually looks specifically for submodules (`git submodule`).  The other is just the `git status` command.